Workflow on two identical branches works on one, but not on the other
I have two identical GitHub branches. When I try to run GitHub Actions on my main branch, job "Build with Gradle" fails because the tests do not pass. When I try to run GitHub Actions on my other branch, everything works right and build ends with success, all my tests successfully passing. Locally my tests pass alright as well.
I tried to get some more detailed logs from tests, but they say nothing.

There are two possible explanations : either you think the branches are identical but they aren't (you can check this by pasting the output of git diff branch1 branch2), or the tests you run rely on the branch name or its context (in this case, you'll have to look for it manually). You say "(the logs) say nothing", are you sure ? Not even a stack trace or an error source ? This might be a good starting point
